# How to set remembering cookies in WebKitGTK (C++)?

Tags: c++, webkitgtk

I created WebKitGTK wrapper, and works fine, but don't remberer cookies. This is main.cpp file (I use [webview/webview (on Github)](https://github.com/webview/webview):

```cpp
#include "webview.h"
#ifdef WIN32
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInt, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow) {
#else
int main() {
#endif
  webview::webview w(true, nullptr);
  w.set_title("WebKitGTK");
  w.set_size(3840, 2160, WEBVIEW_HINT_NONE);
  w.navigate("https://google.com");
  w.run();
  return 0;
}
```

Do you know how to set WebKitGTK to remember cookies?

Comment: What do you mean by remembering cookies? They are cached in memory and no addition actions are required.

Comment: What I mean is that if I click on accept on the cookie message, it shouldn't ask me again the next time I start the app.